# Direct URL to overlay on the page

Tags: url, overlay

I have an overlay on my page and I would like to give user a link / URL which leads them directly to the page, with the overlay loaded.
Is it possible to be done? How do I do that?

This is my code:

```
$(function() {

  $('#overlay_job').click(function() {

    document.getElementById('iframe_job').src = "http://targeturl-for-my-overlay-content";

    $('#overlay_bg2').fadeIn('fast',function(){
      $('#overlay_box').fadeIn('fast');
    });
  });

  $('#boxclose').click(function() {
    $('#overlay_box').fadeOut('fast',function() {
      $('#overlay_bg2').fadeOut('fast');
    });
  });

  var overlay_bg2 = $("#overlay_box");
  //var top = $(window).scrollTop() - (overlay_bg2.outerHeight() / 2);
  var top=0;
  var left = -(overlay_bg2.outerWidth() / 2);

  overlay_bg2.css({ 'margin-top': top,'margin-left': left });

  if(getUrlVars()["openJobOverLay"] == "Y") {
         $('#overlay_job').trigger('click');
  }
});

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
              function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
              });
  return vars;
}
```

===========
and on the page, user can click on this link to get the overlay shown:

```
<a id="overlay_job" class="underline" href="javascript:void(0);%20opener.jobframe.location.reload();">
See job openings
</a>
<img src="link_arrow.gif" class="linkarrow">
</div>
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hide the overlay with CSS: `display: none;`. Give the overlay element an `id`, then add the `id` to the URL like so `http://www.yourpage.com#id`. Then use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) $('#' + window.location.hash).show();
});
```

**Edit:**

In your specific case add this line as the last line inside your `$(document.ready();`.

```
$(function() {

  // All of your code inside this function...

  if(window.location.hash) $('#' + window.location.hash).click();

});

function getUrlVars() { 

// Some more of your code...
```

Comment: Hi, may I know for
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) $('#' + window.location.hash).show();
});
do I need to make any change to the above before adding it into my code? (apologies I am quite a beginner in this, so might have asked a stupid question. :p)

Comment: Include jQuery `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` inside the `<head>` section or at the bottom of your page. Then it should work just like that.

Comment: seems it is not working for my file. below is my code, did I miss something?

Comment: Edit your question and stick it in there?